# django south migration error relation "photo_photo" already exists

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am using Django South.I am following the tutorial of http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

first of all i want to give some information about my project and the apps.
I have a django app namely `photo` and i have two model namely `Photo` and `UserCommission`.

these are the models

```
class Photo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
   approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
   approved_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True,blank=True)
   uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField()
   description = models.CharField(max_length = 500 , blank = False , null = True)
```

and

```
class UserCommission(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        created_time = models.DateTimeField('Created Time',auto_now_add=True)
        commission = models.IntegerField()
        photo_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='commission_image')
        download = models.DateTimeField()
        photo_id = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

for my first migration i have applied the following according to the tutorial,

```
python manage.py schemamigration photo --initial
```

and immediately i have apply the following command

```
python manage.py migrate photo
```

then i made a change in my `Photo` model and apply the following command for final migration

```
  python manage.py schemamigration photo --auto
```

and

```
  python manage.py migrate photo
```

and finally my first migration has successfully done and the edited columns are added in the `Photo` model!

now in another situation,i have to make change in my `UserCommission` model and for that i have followed the same process i have followed for my first migration.but after the last command for this second  migration that is

```
python manage.py migrate photo
```

i am facing the following error

Running migrations for photo:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_initial.

> photo:0001_initial
>   FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "photo_photo" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "photo" varchar(100) NULL, "approved" boolean NOT NULL, "approved_time" timestamp with time zone NULL, "uploaded_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "description" varchar(500) NULL, "keyword" varchar(500) NULL, "image_id" varchar(300) NULL, "Certified" boolean NOT NULL, "approved_by" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "user_id" integer NOT NULL, "total_download" integer NOT NULL, "watermarked_image" varchar(100) NULL, "dpi_value" integer NOT NULL)
>   The error was: relation "photo_photo" already exists
>   Error in migration: photo:0001_initial
>   DatabaseError: relation "photo_photo" already exists

```
DatabaseError: relation "photo_photo" already exists
```

and tell you what, its really bothering me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like that migration has already been applied and the database thinks it hasn't. You can always `migrate --fake` to just update the table in the database without trying to apply the migration.

In your case, it looks like you need to (at least) `python manage.py migrate photo --fake 0002`. You may have to do this for more than one migration depending on how many you have and what you've done.