# django south how to add a new model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I am usign Django South for the first time.I have already succeed to update my database using Django South without deleting my whole database.
This was the query [django south migration error relation “photo_photo” already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735525/django-south-migration-error-relation-photo-photo-already-exists)

but i am facing a error whenever i want to  add a **new model**.*In mention i have added all the staff in my admin.py file*

The above given query was about the **change in a existing model** and thankfully i have successfully updated my database.

But after following the same command from [South Tutorial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html) ,i can not able to add a new model in my database,apparently the model is showing in the django admin site,but after i click on to that model or after i want save anything on to that model,i am facing the following error

```
DatabaseError at /admin/photo/userreferralcode/
relation "photo_userreferralcode" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photo_userreferralcode"
```

My model.py

```
class UserReferralCode(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my admin.py

```
from app.models import UserReferralCode 

admin.site.register(UserReferralCode)
```

and i have also added `admin.autodiscover()`
 in my main `urls.py`.

in mention for a new migration(since i have intended to add a new model)i have wrote the following command step by step

first

```
python manage.py schemamigration photo --initial
```

then second

```
python manage.py migrate photo
```

then third

```
python manage.py schemamigration photo --auto
```

then fourth

```
python manage.py migrate photo
```

then

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

after doing all these staff the model `UserReferralCode` has been added in the django admin site ,i can see it,but clicking on this newly added model or after saving anything on this model,i am facing the above given error,i am giving it here again.

```
 DatabaseError at /admin/photo/userreferralcode/
 relation "photo_userreferralcode" does not exist
 LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photo_userreferralcode"
```

**in mention my app name is photo**

now whats the problem or what i am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

`--initial` is used when first migration for application created. After that `--auto` is used every time you change models or add new one. (For another django application you run `--initial` with its first migration, and so on)

So, considering your previous question, you should apply the following steps:

1. Add `Photo` and `UserCommission` to your `models.py`.
2. `python manage.py schemamigration photo --initial`.
3. `python manage.py migrate photo`.
4. (Made changes and create migrations for them)
5. Add `UserReferralCode` to `models.py`.
6. `python manage.py schemamigration photo --auto`.
7. `python manage.py migrate photo`.

By the way, once you get used `migrate`, you don't have to use `syncdb`, since `migrate` intended to replace `syncdb` in a more convenient way.